# i need this svg iframe code to be responsive

Tags: css, svg, iframe

```
<div class="textwidget custom-html-widget">
<iframe width="90%" height="800px" frameborder="0" align="middle" scrolling="no" src="USAmap.svg"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:amcharts="http://amcharts.com/ammap" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
    <defs>
        <style type="text/css">
            ...

        </style>
    </defs>
    <g>
        ...

    </g>
</svg></iframe>
```

I need this html code to be responsive.Map is not working on mobile

Comment: add a viewBox attribute

Comment: when i add this viewbox to svg map not loading

Comment: presumably you don't have reasonable values in it. Hard to say without a proper [mcve] though.